# Twitter API, Tweepy, get_user_time_line bug

Tags: python, api, rest, twitter, tweepy

I am working on a Twitter bot based on Elon Musk tweets, retrieving his user_timeline() every 1s, I have tested it on other users tweets (users with lower followers) and it works just fine, however for Elon's after a few of correct retrievals it crashes, is that an API issue, or is it something related to Request Limits, please let me know if u have any idea how why that is happening cuz I've been struggling for the past few hours? Thank you for your response.

Comment: What is the nature of the crash, what error are you seeing? Can you share the code?

Comment: Basically I manage to retrieve Elon's last tweet correctly for several times, but after a while it seems there are consistency issues. I am sending a get request to the Twitter API every second, and I get a correct json object back, but after a while I get an empty response on the get request like []. I've tried Twitter v1.1 also v2. On a side note this issue is only on accounts with a lot of followers, when I run the bot based on other users with less followers it works just fine.